# How to run websockets deamon in Laravel Forge

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I make a simple server using Laravel for websocket purposes using [Laravel-Websocket](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/getting-started/introduction.html)

The server managed to run well on **Laravel Forge**, it's just that I can't execute the `php artisan websockets:serve` command on deamon.

The error message I found is
[image: Error message]

Is there anything I miss in this case?

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/78 could this help you?

Comment: Hi@cbaconnier still the same output